# Checking if members are initiated yet in constructor

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, pixi.js

I have a class that extends `PIXI.Text` which overrides the default `this.text` with something like so:

```
    set text(newText: string) {
        super.text = newText
        this.updateToolTipText(newText)
    }
```

The problem is that:

1. `set text` gets called during the construction of the class
2. and `this.udpateToolTipText()` uses `this.width` to adjust the container size

BUT when called during the construction of the class, `this.width` isn't defined yet and throws this error:

`TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'style.styleID')`

I've tried `if(this.width == undefined) return` and `if(this.width == null) return` but nothing seems to prevent this error from triggering. After construction is complete, the class behaves as expected, this is only being thrown during construction.

I've hacked around this solution by creating a dummy variable to return out during construction but I just don't understand how/why I can't check if `this.width` exists without throwing the error.

Edit: Adding code snippets below.

```
export class TextView extends PIXI.Text {

    constructor(text: string, x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number, container: PIXI.Container,
                fontSize: number = GameFont.Size.Normal, color: string = GameColor.getColor(GameColor.Color.Gray0), centerY: boolean = true) {
        super(text)

        // more irrelevant code below
    }

}
```

Where following the `super` trail leads to `this.text` being updated. The function being called looks like this:

```
    private updateToolTipText(newText: string) {
        // if(this.width == null) return // <= this doesn't help
        // if(this.width == undefined) return // <= this also doesn't help
        if(this.width < this.initialW) return  // <= error is being triggered in this line during construction. When I remove this line the class constructs without errors but then the code doesn't work the way it's supposed to.

        // more irrelevant code below
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your constructor and `udpateToolTipText` as well? Especially showing your attempt to use checks for `this.width`? Then we can actually advise where the issue is

Comment: @FredStark I edited the original post to include some more code. Is this helpful?

Comment: what happened when you had `if(this.width == null)`? Did it give you an error or did it just not perform correctly? Was the issue that the tooltip text was not updated? If so, you could add a call to `updateToolTipText` at the end of the constructor, once all the dependencies are available

Comment: It throws the exact same error and crashes the app. Seems like it's trying to use `this.width` to evaluate if `this.width` exists.

Comment: I just went looking for the error again and realised it actually doesn't mention width at all. Why do you think it's width that's the issue? Is there a stacktrace? Where is `style.styleID` evaluated? Does width have a setter or getter that checks style?

Comment: I haven't look too deeply into the issue but I've tried multiple iterations of the function and I narrowed it down to the usage of `this.width`. I can reference any other variable in the function and nothing errors out. As soon as I try to use `this.width` the entire app crashes with this error.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't enough information in your question to be able to answer this